# Cannot login with JSON

Tags: python, json, django, authentication

I'm going to test my Django app, so I've created a JSON file named 'users.py', this file contains the following code:

```
[
{
     "pk": 1, 
     "model": "auth.user", 
     "fields": {
          "username": "JLeivinha", 
          "first_name": "", 
          "last_name": "", 
          "is_active": true, 
          "is_superuser": false, 
          "is_staff": false, 
          "last_login": "2015-09-22T10:53:40.913", 
          "groups": [], 
          "user_permissions": [], 
          "password": "hdishfi1", 
          "email": "leivinha@hotmail.com", 
          "date_joined": "2015-09-22T10:53:40.913"
     }
},
{
     "pk": 2, 
     "model": "auth.user", 
     "fields": {
          "username": "DFarel", 
          "first_name": "", 
          "last_name": "", 
          "is_active": true, 
          "is_superuser": false, 
          "is_staff": false, 
          "last_login": "2015-09-22T10:53:40.913", 
          "groups": [], 
          "user_permissions": [], 
          "password": "mxoasjw2", 
          "email": "diegof611@gmail.com", 
          "date_joined": "2015-09-22T10:53:40.913"
     }
}
]
```

But it doesn't work: My app loaded the created users from JSON file, but now I can't login with anyone of these (error 'matching query does not exist').
Anybody can help me? Thanks ;)

Comment: Can we see the part of the code supposed to log in users ?

Comment: I guess those are testusers, but just watch out with posting passwords (and email addresses)

Comment: IIRC the password has to be encrypted - the fixture is loaded verbatim in the database

Answer (score 1):

The passwords in the fixture have to be encrypted, `loaddata` will *not* take care of this. The function to encrypt passwords is `django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password`, you can use it manually from the django shell:

```
(o2)bruno@bigb:/var/www/playground/project$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
>>> make_password('mxoasjw2')
u'pbkdf2_sha256$15000$uvORWeKIoaUS$ISPMoXbc68VRadS94dD8q7MwD43RDsdjiprpOwbQEQ0='
```

Comment: Maybe not needed for instructional purposes, but one should (probably) always use a salt when hashing passwords.

Comment: @MathieuB : `make_password` asks the current `hasher` for a salt if not provided at call time.